# Traceback (most recent call last): convert_model.py

Tags: python, keras

When implementing the code:
https://github.com/fizyr/keras-retinanet
Below is the code of convert_model.py script

```
  # Allow relative imports when being executed as script.
if __name__ == "__main__" and __package__ is None:
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', '..'))
    import keras_retinanet.bin  # noqa: F401
    __package__ = "keras_retinanet.bin"

# Change these to absolute imports if you copy this script outside the keras_retinanet package.
from keras_retinanet.models import load_model
model_path = os.path.join('..', 'snapshots', 'resnet50_coco_best_v2.1.0.h5')
model = load_model(model_path, backbone_name='resnet50')
```

Executing the convert_model.py script, the below error occured:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convert_model.py", line 33, in <module>
    model = load_model(model_path, backbone_name='resnet50')
  File "..\..\keras_retinanet\models\__init__.py", line 83, in load_model
    model = keras.models.load_model(filepath, custom_objects=backbone(backbone_name).custom_objects)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 249, in load_model
    f = h5py.File(filepath, mode='r')
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py", line 312, in __init__
    fid = make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, swmr=swmr)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py", line 142, in make_fid
    fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py\h5f.pyx", line 78, in h5py.h5f.open
OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = '..\snapshots\resnet50_coco_best_v2.1.0.h5', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)
```

Could you please help me fix the issue?

Comment: You have to show your code to us.

Comment: Did you read the error?

Comment: Yes I did. I am a beginner to this and couldn't understand what it said. I even tried googling but haven't got the required answer.

Comment: If you just took the repo and ran it without changing anything, you're going to run into issues since you haven't updated the paths - doesn't pertain to the model per se.

Comment: I have mentioned the code I've taken from the source. But I did actually update the paths in my code, rest is all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the file referenced downloaded and that it is in the same folder as your current python script. Then change the last line to:

model = load_model('filename', backbone_name='resnet50')

Comment: When you say referenced file, does that mean weights of the model? What does it mean?

Comment: '..\snapshots\resnet50_coco_best_v2.1.0.h5' 'this file

Comment: Yes. the referenced file is in the right path, I verified it again.